# can't upadte mongodb schema if its null using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update my 2nd schema which is set to null
for eg. this is my output look like

```
{
      "_id": "6145b0c7331a5a4634640f27",
      "ownerId": "b0jyt9gvktpl6936",
      "fname": "Gravity",
      "lname": "Movie",
      "shopPlace": null,
      "createdAt": "2021-09-18T09:26:31.801Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-09-18T09:26:31.801Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
```

and my schema look like this

ownerSchema.js

```
var ownerSchema = Schema({
    ownerId   : String,
    fname     : String,
    lname     : String,
    shopPlace : { 
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Shop'
                },
    shopType    String
});
var Owner = mongoose.model('Owner', ownerSchema);
```

shopSchema.js

```
var shopSchema = Schema({
    _id       : String,
    shopName  : String,
    location  : String,
    startDate : Date,
    endDate   : Date
});
var Shop  = mongoose.model('Shop', shopSchema);
```

and my function update look like this

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let update = {};
  let updateShop = {}
  if (req.body.fname) update.fname = req.body.fname;
  if (req.body.lname) update.lname = req.body.lname;
  if (req.body.shopPlace.shopName) updateShop.shopPlace.shopName = req.body.shopPlace.shopName;
  if (req.body.shopPlace.location) updateShop.shopPlace.location = req.body.shopPlace.location;

   const { shopPlace } = await Owner.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: id },
      {
        $set: update,
      },
      { new:true}
     );

    let newShop = await Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
     { _id: shopPlace },
      {
        $set: updateShop,
      },
      {new:true}
     );

};
```

If my shop schema look like this i can easily update it by postman

```
"shopPlace":{
             "shopName":"Juice Center",
             "location":"mumbai"
            }
```

but if the shopPlace is null and then I trying to update my shop schema its won't update my schema and its look like same

```
"shopPlace":null
```

Comment: *but if the shopPlace is null and then I trying to update my shop schema its won't update my schema* => how it will update if it is `null`, is there any document having  `_id: null` in shop collection?

Comment: no @turivishal as I made if else statement that if user dont want to add shop then it will null incase in future if it want to update his shop that's why i am trying to update shop as well

Comment: your question is not clear, are you trying to insert document in shop collection if it is null?

Comment: yes I am trying to insert data if it is null that's why i am trying to update my shop schema

Comment: okay and also update that _id in owner collection right?

Comment: How it will insert document while you are trying to update it using `findOneAndUpdate`? try to use `save` method if it returns null.

Comment: yes @turivishal but my question is if the schema already have data then too i have to use `save()` ?

Comment: no you can update, if i understand your question you want something like, `if (shopPlace == null) then use save(updateShop) else findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: `if(shopPlace==null){ save(updateShop); else( findOneAndUpdate }` ?

Comment: Hi i tried but its not saving @turivishal

Comment: Your question is not clear, i can not understand the exact problem.

Comment: see I want to update my `shopPlace` if its is `null` here my `shopDetail` is ref from my `Shop` Schema If You want to know why my `shopPlace` is `null` then the reason is its option user want to add or not its upto user but incase he/she want to add `shopPlace` in future then it can be updated from `null` to provided detail but here I can't update it @turivishal

Comment: how to find the document in shop schema while `shopPlace` is null?

Comment: by `Owner` schema here I am using `Owner.findOneAndUpdate()` to upfate my owner Schema and to update every keys  @turivishal

Comment: But the field `shopPlace` in Owner collection is null, there is no document in shop schema.

Comment: yes `shopPlace` in owner collection is `null` thats why i want to update it @turivishal

Comment: yes try to understnad tha thing, you need to do two operations for that 1) you have to insert it in shop schema first 3) then that shop id you have to update in owner collection in `shopPlace`.

Comment: ok 1. i have inserted new schema 2. how will i update to `shopPlace` @turivishal

Comment: using third query.

Comment: n what will be my third query ? @turivishal

Comment: the update query, `await Owner.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: { shopPlace: "that you have inserted new" } })`

Answer (score 0):

ownerSchema.js:

```
var ownerSchema = Schema({
    ownerId   : String,
    fname     : String,
    lname     : String,
    shopPlace : { 
                  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                  ref: 'Shop'
                  default: 'null'
                },
    shopType    String
});
var Owner = mongoose.model('Owner', ownerSchema);
```